# xcode 5: How to convert a storyboard to make advantage of the xcode 5 advantages? And why?

Tags: interface-builder, storyboard, xcode5

I just opened a storyboard for the first time after installing xcode 5. (Usually I keep a tab open with the storyboard. Apparently xcode treads this differently. Now I opened it.) 
Then I was asked whether I want to convert the storyboard so that it can make advantage of new fatures in xcode 5. I pressed "later" or "no" and did regret that in the very next moment.

Two questions here: What are these advantages with respect to storyboards/IB?
How can I perform this automatic conversion afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem the first time I opened xcode 5 after upgrading by not selecting to convert the storyboard. I couldn't find any doco on how to do it later either.

I used the following workaround to convert from an iOS 6.1 to 7.0 storyboard:

1. Opened the old storyboard ("MainStoryboard.storyboard") in IB and selected all storyboard elements and copied them
2. Created a new blank storyboard and pasted them into it ("Storyboard7.storyboard")
3. In the document outline view of the new storyboard there were a few little gold error arrows next to some of the view controllers. Clicking those showed "Misaligned Views". These were controls whose frames now did not match their auto-layout constraints. I accepted all the suggested fixes.
4. In the project's target properties, updated the storyboard for the project under "Main storyboard file base name" from MainStoryboard to Storyboard7

Answer (score 4):

Just encountered the same problem myself, and stumbled across this question looking for an answer. Finally managed to find the solution (there was an obscure hint in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)):

1. Open the storyboard file in Interface Builder
2. Go to the File Inspector (leftmost icon on right-hand bar)
3. Under **Interface Builder Document**, drop down *Opens In* and select "Default (5.0)"

After a moment, it will load the iOS-7 version of the Storyboard.